# Optimize NHibernate: Load all data from specified tables

Tags: nhibernate, caching, optimization, fluent-nhibernate, prefetch

**Scenario:** I have built an ASP.NET MVC application that manages my cooking recipes. I am using FluentNHibernate to access data from the following tables:

1. Users
2. Categories
3. Recipes
4. RecipeCategories *(many-to-many junction table)*
5. UserBookmarkedRecipes *(many-to-many junction table)*
6. UserCookedRecipes *(many-to-many junction table)*

**Question:** Is there any way to tell NHibernate to load all data from all tables listed above and store it in memory / in NHibernate's cache so that there do not have to be any additional database requests?

---

**Motivation behind question:** The variety of many-to-many relationships poses a problem and would greatly benefit from that optimization.

**Note regarding data:** The overall amount of data is extremely small. We are talking about less than 100 recipes at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of preloading everything, I would suggest loading once and then holding it as it's accessed.

NHibernate maintains two different caches, and does a pretty good job of keeping them in sync with your underlying data store.  By default, it uses what is called a "first level" cache on a per-session basis but I don't think that's what you want.  You can read about the differences at the [nhibernate faq page on caching](http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/28/first-and-second-level-caching-in-nhibernate)

I suspect a second level cache is what you need (this is available throughout your app).  You'll need to get a cache provider from [NHContrib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/files/NHibernate.Caches/) (download the version that matches your version of NHibernate).  The SysCache2 provider will probably be the easiest to set up for your scenario, as long as your app will be the ONLY thing writing to the database.  If other processes will be writing, you will need to ensure that all are using the same cache as an intermediary if you want it to stay in sync.

The second level cache is configured with a timeout that you can set to whatever you need.  Don't think it can be infinite but you can set it to long periods if you want (probably not a terrible idea to go back to DB from time to time though).  If you want to preload everything up front, you can simply access all your entities from your global.asax's Application_Start method, but this shouldn't be necessary.

You will need to configure your session factory to use the cache.  Call the .Cache(...) method when fluently configuring your session factory, it should be relatively self-explanatory.

You will also need to set Cache.ReadWrite() in both your entity mappings AND your relationship mappings.  You can do this by convention or by calling Cache.ReadWrite() in your fluent mappings.

Something like:

```
public class RecipeMap : ClassMap<Recipe> {
    public RecipeMap () {
        Cache.ReadWrite();
        Id(x => x.Id);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Ingredients).Cache.ReadWrite();
    }
}
```

On the Cache calls in your mappings you can specify ReadOnly or whatever else you may need.  NonStrictReadWrite is an interesting one, it can boost performance significantly but at an increased risk of reading stale data from the cache.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, I really appreciate the effort. However, I have a question: As far as I understood your description of the first level cache operating on a per-session basis, I'd consider this caching method more appropriate for my scenario. For 99% of the time, only a single user is logged in at the same time; to access any data, that user has to be signed in. After knowing more about my application, do you still think the NHContrib `SysCache2` is more appropriate, and if yes, what do think are the disadvantages of the first level cache?

Comment: **Update:** I'm sorry, I've read the term *session* and thought of an ASP.NET session (which would have been what I wanted to achieve). I understand the difference now, and you're right: that behavior is not what I try to achieve.

Comment: This depends on what your session management strategy - typically in a web app the session's lifetime is a single request (think NH session, not web session).  Some apps simply get a new session per page/control, or even per call to nhibernate.  The first-level cache is not intended to be long lived, but to optimize within a single unit of work.  So yes, I think that the second level is still more appropriate for your scenario.  I'd only rely on first level for this type of caching if using a single-session winforms app with an embedded database like SQLite.

Comment: Exactly, I thought of web session, not NH session. I'll accept your answer as soon as possible!